# Python script not exiting on sys.exit()

Tags: python, python-3.x

sys.exit is not happening here. I have tried, `quit`, `exit` etc..
Any suggestions?

```
    try:
        print ("Cloning Git Repo")
        os.system("git clone " + options.clone_url)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Git Clone Failed")
        sys.exit(2)

    try:
        print ("Building Docker Image")
        os.system("docker build -t " + options.image_tag + " -f " + repo_name + "/" + DOCKERFILE)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Docker Build Failed", e)
        sys.exit(2)

    try:
        print ("Tagging Docker Image")
        os.system("docker tag " + options.image_tag + " " + PORTUS_REPO_URL + "/" + options.image_tag)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Docker Tag Failed", e)
        sys.exit(2)
```

Output:

```
Cloning Git Repo
Cloning into 'xxx'...
git@git.hashedin.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Building Docker Image
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
Tagging Docker Image
Error parsing reference: "http://portus.hashedin.com/nginx" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
Pushing Docker Image
```

Comment: It is not printing "Git clone failed!" either, so the problem is not the `sys.exit()`, but that your script is not even reaching this point. It seems that Git Clone produces an internal error which you could not catch.

Comment: What makes you think `os.system()` would throw an exception? When I read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), I would expect an integer return value

Comment: you would have to use functions from module `subprocess` to get exit code from `docker` and use it to run `sys.exit()` - see ie. [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, i have fixed the issue with subprocess

Answer (score 3):

Exception is never raised because os.system not raising exceptions. Please use subprocess instead [Python3 subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use your code as below using python3 subprocess : https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess

log = subprocess.Popen("git clone " + options.clone_url,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# GET BOTH THE ERROR LOG AND OUTPUT LOG FOR IT
stdout,stderr = log.communicate()

# FORMAT THE OUTPUT
stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
stderr = stderr.decode('utf-8')

if stderr != "" :
    Tlog("ERROR WHILE CLONING GIT URL \n\n\t"+ options.clone_url +'\n')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix by using below code.

```
    print("Building Docker Image")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ['sudo', 'docker', 'build', '-t', options.image_tag, '.'])
    proc.wait()
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
    if proc.returncode != 0:
        print("Docker Build Failed")
        sys.exit(2)
```

Its working perfectly.